# Windows Flash CS2 font not showing?

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

I Installed the font into my system/font folder. But font is not showing. Font is showing in the word document but will not showing in the flash. Will you plz give me solutions. I am waiting for your response.

Thanks & regards,
Basant..

Comment: *Windows*. *Flash*. These might be the sources of your problem. ;)

Comment: I have installed on my system/font folder. So how can i solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your talking about the dropdown selection for choosing a font, restart flash - if it doesnt work, it could be the name of the font.

For example I had trouble using a font called "j.d.". It had period's in the name and flash wouldn't use it. I renamed the file in the windows font folder and then it was under a different name in the list.

If your refering to it being invisible on the stage or when your running it, you may have the dynamic text textfield rotated without embed. that would not work in CS2 with system fonts.

it could be a case of tiny font size, or its white and your background is white.

You kind of need to be more specific with the problem your having. Does the font show up in the rest of the suite?

What type of font is it and whats its name? where did you get it from?

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your response. The font name is "Boopee-bold". I got this font from torrent. Because it is Paid one.That is why a download from there.